# Line Graph on top of MultiBar Graph NVD3, d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

[NVD3](http://nvd3.org/) have [multi bar chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBar.html) and [line plus bar chart](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html). But it seem like, there isn't something like multibar plus line chart.

I sort of played around line plus bar chart to make it multi bar line chart.

Here is the format in which line plus bar graph accepts data:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "Quantity",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 127], [1138683600000, 271]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price",
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 71.89], [1138683600000, 75.51]]
  }
]
```

So to add multiple bars in this, i tried changing the data to:

```
[
  {
    "key" : "Quantity",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 127], [1138683600000, 271]]
  },
    {
    "key" : "Quantity1",
    "bar": true,
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 127], [1138683600000, 271]]
  },
  {
    "key" : "Price",
    "values" : [[1136005200000, 71.89], [1138683600000, 75.51]]
  }
]
```

This shows both labels, Quantity and Quantity1 at the top but to total no of bars is still two(one for each instead of two for each).

Since I am getting the labels at the top, I somehow feel that this is doable :)

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azitabh/zq7DK/1/).

Explaining the problem statement: Lets say there is a book store with various books. I want to show the max and min no of book sold in a day over a period of one month as bars and total sale in that month as line graph. So for every month on x axis, there should be two bars and one point(for line graph).

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Comment: So in a line plus bar graph in nvd3, you have one bar and one point(line is formed by joining these) per value of x. What i want is two bar and one point per value of x.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in nvd3. You're better off trying in pure D3.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer to this question for anyone else wondering is to either set stacked to true in nv.models.multiChart or create another model based on nv.models.multiChart.

```
    bars1 = nv.models.multiBar().stacked(true).yScale(yScale1),
    bars2 = nv.models.multiBar().stacked(true).yScale(yScale2)
```

Line number in source code:

https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/multiChart.js#L34

And I'm passing data in like so:

```
data.push({
                    type: "bar",
                    key: series.name,
                    values: seriesData,
                    yAxis: 1
                }
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Check multiChart.html example from nvd3 package examples. This example uses multiChart type and displays 2 line points, 2 area points and 3 bars per each x point, so it can also display just 2 bars and 1 line point.

Comment: This does not answer his question. He's talking about MultiBargraphs combined with a line graph